Db GetCreateConnection() should be closed on End on import Dynamics CRM organization
Dynamics CRM 365 v9.1.26.23 on-premise
I'm trying to import an organization to a new CRM environment from the exact same one (version, language, server parameters). An error occurs during the import process
2024-12-24 11:22:56.162|   Info| Organization marked as having reports published
2024-12-24 11:22:56.162|   Info| Updating language packs
2024-12-24 11:23:31.230|  Error| Error while updating organization information: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: ValidateClosed - Db GetCreateConnection() should be closed on End
   в Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.ValidateClosed(Boolean raiseException)
   в Microsoft.Crm.LegacySqlDataAccessContextImplementation.EndRequest()
   в Microsoft.Crm.SqlDataAccessContext.OnEndRequest()
   в Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ExecutionContext.OnEndRequest()
   в Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.UpdateOrganizationInfo(Guid organizationId, OrganizationGroupsInfo organizationInfo, String organizationFriendlyName, String organizationUniqueName, Uri reportServerUrl, Int32 PercentUpdateOrganization, ICollection`1 users, OrgType orgType)
2024-12-24 11:23:31.230|  Error| Import Organization (Name=CRM, Id=5ef8e692-b83a-4ada-aef8-edd8e1604bb6) failed with Exception:
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: ValidateClosed - Db GetCreateConnection() should be closed on End
   в Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.ValidateClosed(Boolean raiseException)
   в Microsoft.Crm.LegacySqlDataAccessContextImplementation.EndRequest()
   в Microsoft.Crm.SqlDataAccessContext.OnEndRequest()
   в Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ExecutionContext.OnEndRequest()
   в Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.UpdateOrganizationInfo(Guid organizationId, OrganizationGroupsInfo organizationInfo, String organizationFriendlyName, String organizationUniqueName, Uri reportServerUrl, Int32 PercentUpdateOrganization, ICollection`1 users, OrgType orgType)
   в Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.Import(Guid organizationId, String organizationUniqueName, String organizationFriendlyName, String sqlServerName, String databaseName, Uri reportServerUrl, ICollection`1 users, MultipleTenancy multipleTenancy, Boolean patchOnImport, OrgDbUpdateMode orgDbUpdateMode, OrgType orgType)
2024-12-24 11:23:31.434|   Info| Found the older table DBUpdateInstallInfo_V5, updating new table and deleting
2024-12-24 11:23:31.481|   Info| GetDBUpdateRevisionThresholdForServer(): Threshold = 9.1.0026.0023.
2024-12-24 11:30:11.118|  Error| Import Organization (Name=CRM, Id=5ef8e692-b83a-4ada-aef8-edd8e1604bb6) failed with Exception:
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: ValidateClosed - Db GetCreateConnection() should be closed on End
   в Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.ValidateClosed(Boolean raiseException)
   в Microsoft.Crm.LegacySqlDataAccessContextImplementation.EndRequest()
   в Microsoft.Crm.SqlDataAccessContext.OnEndRequest()
   в Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ExecutionContext.OnEndRequest()
   в Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.UpdateOrganizationInfo(Guid organizationId, OrganizationGroupsInfo organizationInfo, String organizationFriendlyName, String organizationUniqueName, Uri reportServerUrl, Int32 PercentUpdateOrganization, ICollection`1 users, OrgType orgType)
   в Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.Import(Guid organizationId, String organizationUniqueName, String organizationFriendlyName, String sqlServerName, String databaseName, Uri reportServerUrl, ICollection`1 users, MultipleTenancy multipleTenancy, Boolean patchOnImport, OrgDbUpdateMode orgDbUpdateMode, OrgType orgType)

At this point the process stops.
If I make a backup of an existing organization on a new environment and import it, everything goes without problems.
I tried increasing the OLEDBTimeout and ExtendedTimeout registry parameters, but it had no effect.

Disabling the Async-service during import helped solve the problem.
